# Any ideas on $ \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{x^{a-1}}{(1+x)^{b-1}(1+x-xy)}dx$?

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

I tried to use the Beta integral representation but it isn't working here. Please any help will be appreciated.

$$ \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{x^{a-1}}{(1+x)^{b-1}(1+x-xy)}dx$$ where $ a,b \in \mathbb{Z^{+}}$.

Comment: You have to find out how $x^{a-1}$ can be build up as a polynom of $x+1$. E.g. $x^2:=(x+1)^2+a(x+1)+b$, then determine $a$ and $b$. Then the integral becomes easier to solve.

Answer (score 3):

---

Define for natural numbers $\left(m,n\right)\in\mathbb{N}^{2}$ and real number $z\in\mathbb{R}$,

$$I_{m,n}{\left(z\right)}:=\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{x^{m-1}}{\left(1+x\right)^{n-1}\left(1+x-zx\right)}\,\mathrm{d}x;~~~\small{m<n\land z<1}.$$

The linear-fractional transformation $\frac{x}{1+x}=t\implies x=\frac{t}{1-t}$ puts the integral into the form of Euler's representation for Gauss's hypergeometric function ${_2F_1}$:

$$\begin{align}
I_{m,n}{\left(z\right)}
&=\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{x^{m-1}}{\left(1+x\right)^{n-1}\left(1+x-zx\right)}\,\mathrm{d}x\\
&=\int_{0}^{1}\frac{\left(\frac{t}{1-t}\right)^{m-1}}{\left(\frac{1}{1-t}\right)^{n-2}\left(1-zt\right)}\,\mathrm{d}t;~~~\small{\left[\frac{x}{1+x}=t\right]}\\
&=\int_{0}^{1}\frac{t^{m-1}\left(1-t\right)^{n-m-1}}{1-zt}\,\mathrm{d}t\\
&=\operatorname{B}{\left(m,n-m\right)}\,{_2F_1}{\left(1,m;n;z\right)}.\blacksquare\\
\end{align}$$

---

Comment: "+1" actually i transformed the result you got into the integral above and was then seeking if any closed form exists. I was trying to generalise the hypergeometric function.